# Add to UIWindow views hierarchy in UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uiwindow

my question is very simple but I cant find answer... 
I have a tab bar and Im trying to add view above view to get custom segue animation but for some reason when Im insert Subview, the subview added after the tab bar layer and not in the tab bar layer after the `AddPod` view:
here is example:

[image]

```
override func perform() {
    let sourceView = self.source.view as UIView
    let destinationView = self.destination.view as UIView

    destinationView.frame.origin.y = -destinationView.frame.size.height

    let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!
    window?.insertSubview(destinationView, aboveSubview: sourceView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                    destinationView.frame.origin.y = 0
    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        self.source.tabBarController?.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
}
```